# Create user with Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo

I am trying to create database user through Pymongo 4. Since add_user API is deprecated I have to issue a command on the admin database like this

```
db.command("createUser", username, pwd=password, roles=[{"role":"readWrite", "db": customer_database_name}])
```

Issuing this command works fine on my local mongo instance and ipython but when I tried to create the user on my prod mongo instance I got an error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: User document needs 'credentials' field to be a non-empty object, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "User document needs 'credentials' field to be a non-empty object", 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}
```

Here is the output of printing out the db object that I use to issue the command

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['192.168.1.45:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, authsource='$external', authmechanism='MONGODB-AWS', authmechanismproperties={'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN': 'FwoGZXIvYXdzEEcaDAhhtbMogjl358f1AiKYAc/qgGiNBxqvNu+jxt/zQ56xP0K7se2hL20tv2NwiLGpOeDIxIDoGWOcayQ8pszaoiPzTsqtQuzuFr07MOQ6DWVtbAqk3I38rATSSRKUqgCUFbs1bX3OwVVu04f79YAiuRc2PRtaqr/CLPFBgsLGF9U6bk6xFuAGwfMLEJTpl630mizPsrl9ocbc8PdbVscNuBuEzeNPeRjfKIG2g6gGMh81euxVQfDpmKSm6ziH8I01mc2e3c+0AL/IiuLjx57v'}, tls=True, tlsallowinvalidcertificates=True, appname='<appname>', tlsdisableocspendpointcheck=True), 'admin')
```

I am suspecting this has something to do with the external authsource but not sure how to fix it.